# Display Dokan vendor name and total sales on Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, vendor, dokan

Working with Woocommerce and Dokan plugin. I am trying to display the vendor name and total sales on the vendor info tab (for customer confidence) on single product pages.

Based on *"[Display dokan vendor name on Woocommerce single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145071/display-dokan-vendor-name-on-woocommerce-single-product-pages))"* question thread, I tried this code to display the vendor name and total sales:

```
//show vendor total sales
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_total_sales', 20 );
function show_total_sales() {    
    printf( '<b>Seller Name:</b> <a href="%s">%s</a>', dokan_get_store_url( $author->ID ), $store_info['total_sales'] );
}
```

But it doesn't work. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lighter version of Loic's method for those that just want a shortcode for a link towards the Dokan Store. You can use this on the single product page.

Use the following shortcode: [vendor_shop_name]

Enter Following code in Snippets or functions.php of your theme. Functions.php can be found in theme files ie. html/wp-content/themes/[your_theme]/functions.php

```
/*Shortcode [vendor_shop_name]*/
add_shortcode('vendor_shop_name', 'vendor_shop_name_function');
function vendor_shop_name_function() {
    global $product;
    $seller = get_post_field('post_author', $product->get_id());
    $author  = get_user_by('id', $seller);
    $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get($seller);
    $store_info = dokan_get_store_info($author->ID);
    
    if (!empty($store_info['store_name'])) {
        ?>
            <?php printf('<span><a href=" %s">%s</a></span>', $vendor->get_shop_url(), $vendor->get_shop_name()); ?>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should display the vendor name and total sales on single product pages:

```
// Display vendor total sales
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_total_sales', 20 );
function show_total_sales() {
    global $product;

    $vendor_id   = get_post_field( 'post_author', $product->get_id() ); // Get the author ID (the vendor ID)
    $vendor      = new WP_User($vendor_id); // Get the WP_User object (the vendor) from author ID

    $store_url   = dokan_get_store_url( $vendor_id );  // Get the store URL
    $store_info  = dokan_get_store_info( $vendor_id ); // Get the store data
    $store_name  = $store_info['store_name'];          // Get the store name

    // Output display
    printf( '<p><strong>%s:</strong> <a href="%s">%s (%s %s)</a></p>', 
        __("Seller Name", "woocommerce"), 
        dokan_get_store_url( $vendor_id ),
        $vendor->display_name,
        $store_info['total_sales'],
        _n( "sale", "sales", $store_info['total_sales'], "woocommerce" )
    );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). This should work now.

---

For custom product tab see [Editing product data tabs in Woocommerce *(official docs and code)*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/editing-product-data-tabs/)

Comment: thanks for your help @loictheaztec. but I would like the result to show here - https://prnt.sc/n47815 and not here - https://prnt.sc/n47730. can you do that please? also how can i hide the vendor address in picture 2 and show total sales there instead?

Comment: @ladetunjiosibanjo I don't have Dokan and I have never use it… My code works, but I don't know how to display in that specific Dokan sections. You need to find yourself the correct related hook to replace `woocommerce_single_product_summary` by the right one.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the dokan plugin. I wanna show the vendor info cart to the sidebar. I used your code and make some unpro update. It is in the below code. But I want to display more info about vendors like logo, ratings, button to vendor page, etc.

Here is how my result looks like:

[image: Screenshot fragment]

```php
/**
 * Show sold by on single product page made with Elementor
 * Add the shortcode [dokan_vendor_name] through a short-code widget on single product page
 */
add_shortcode('dokan_vendor_name', 'dokan_store_name_shortcode');

function dokan_store_name_shortcode() {
    global $product;
    $seller = get_post_field('post_author', $product->get_id());
    $author  = get_user_by('id', $seller);
    $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get($seller);
    
    $store_info = dokan_get_store_info($author->ID);
    
    if (!empty($store_info['store_name'])) {
        ?>
        <span class="details">
            <?php printf('**<table style="height: 29px; background-color:  #ccffff; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" width="295"> <tbody> <tr> <td style="width: 285px; text-align: center; "><span style="color: #000000; "><strong>**Sold by:**</strong> <br><a href=" %s">%s</a><br>**    </span></td> </tr> </tbody> </table> ', $vendor->get_shop_url(), $vendor->get_shop_name()); ?>
        </span>
        <?php
    }
}
```