# Woocommerce - Sort products in cart by Author/User in Multi-vendor setup

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, dokan

I have a multivendor Woocommerce shop using [Dokan plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dokan-lite/) and I'm trying to split out the shopping cart into sections based on who the vendor is. **For example:**

- Vendor 1

  - Product C
  - Product B
- Vendor 2

  - Product A

Dokan uses a custom role 'vendor' to extend the user class, so to get the ID of the vendors, I should be able to use something like:

```
$post_data = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] ); 
$vendor_id = $post_data->post_author;
```

This does work, but it will only get the first vendor ID and simply repeats that for all remaining products in the cart. I know this is because I'm not retrieving an array but I can't really find anything in the WP documentation on how to get an array of author IDs (other than wp_list_authors, but that doesn't work well).

As an experiment, I managed to get the splitting + sorting working so long as I'm sorting by categories, since I can use wp_get_post_terms(). I can't replicate this for author data, though...

Current (relevant) code is below:

```
<?php
$cat_sort = array();

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
  $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
  $cat_ids = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

  foreach ( $cat_ids as $id ) {
    $cat_sort[$id][$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
  }                                                    

}

ksort( $cat_sort ); 

$grouped_cart_items = array();
  foreach ( $cat_sort as $cat_id => $cart_items ) {
    $term = get_term( $cat_id, 'product_cat' );                           
?>
<tr>
  <td colspan="6" class=""><strong><?php echo $term->name; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
```

(After this is the actual product loop which shouldn't be important here because their sort ordering happens in the above code)

Any ideas on how I can get author info for the cart products the same way I can get the categories? I'm pretty stumped...

Thanks in advance for any and all assistance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example on how to sort and display cart items by Dokan vendor store name:

```
<table>
<?php

$car_items  = WC()->cart->get_cart(); // Cart items

$items_sort = array(); // Initializing

// Loop through cart items
foreach ( $car_items as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    // Get the vendor_id
    $vendor_id   = get_post_field( 'post_author', $cart_item['product_id'] );

    $store_info  = dokan_get_store_info( $vendor_id ); // Get the store data
    $store_name  = $store_info['store_name'];          // Get the store name

    // Set in multidimentional array the vendor and then the cart item key
    $items_sort[$store_name][$cart_item_key] = $vendor_id;
}

if ( count($car_items) > 1 ) {
    ksort( $items_sort ); // Sorting by vendor name
}

// 1st Loop by vendor name
foreach ( $items_sort as $store_name => $values ) {
    $vendor_id  = reset($values); // The vendor id
    /$store_url = dokan_get_store_url( $vendor_id );  // Get the store URL (if needed)
    ?>
    <tr>
        <!-- Store name display -->
        <td colspan="6" class="store-name"><strong><?php echo $store_name; ?></strong></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    // 2nd Loop the cart items for the vendor name
    foreach( $values as $cart_item_key => $vendor_id) {

        // Retreive the cart item from the cart item key
        $cart_item = $car_items[$cart_item_key];
        ?>
        <tr>
            <!-- Product name display -->
            <td colspan="6" class="product-name"><?php echo $cart_item['data']->get_name(); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php

    } // End of 2nd Loop

} // End of 1st Loop

?>
</table>
```

Related: [Display dokan vendor name on Woocommerce single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145071/display-dokan-vendor-name-on-woocommerce-single-product-pages/51145252#51145252)

Comment: Ohhh! I see what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much for this! get_post_field() is a much better way to get the post_author.
(By the way there's a stray / in front of $store_url. I can't edit it out because the edits need to be 6 characters long, but I thought I'd mention it!)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: Is this code still valid? I get a error "syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file" when try to add them to function.php file.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yes, I saw it. But I think this here would fits better. But I'm not able to add this to my functions.php to test. Do I have to add this in another way?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec ahh.. my bad.. would it be possible to do it via function.php or is it only via template possible?

Comment: Ah, I understand. Means edit the cart.php file in the woocommerce templates folder or via child theme. right?

Comment: @Nik7 Yes that is the way, overriding `cart.php` file copying it to child theme in a "woocommerce" subfolder (but don't edit it in WooCommerce template folder, as you loose all chnages when updating WooCommerce plugin).

Comment: Was able to add it there. This is nice. But If I would use this, I have to add the quantity buttons and remove product link and price and total price. Otherwise I have a cart table + another table with the same informations.I know this is possible.. the question is more, is this smart to do or do we have maybe a lot of side effects?